# Loading PSR-0 incompatible libraries in Laravel 3

Tags: laravel, laravel-3, psr-0

I need to use an old library in Laravel which is not PSR-0 compliant.

It consists of several files and directories with a lot of "require", "include" and "require_once" stuff inside. So, I tried to put it into the "libraries/subfolder" and autoload an entry script but it breaks the framework and I constantly get "Class 'Laravel\Response' not found" error. I can't find the reason of this error but I guess that it somehow breaks Laravel's autoloading system.

How to fix this? How can I load this kind of library and keep things working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody else faces the same problem with Laximo API and Laravel, just use nusoap instead of nusoap_utf8 class.